# How to modify vector elements by a function depending on the element index in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector:

```
my.vector <- rep(0, length.out = 100)
```

I want to modify each element of the vector by a new value depending on the element index.

Of course, I can use a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(my.vector)) {
  my.vector[[i]] <- my.vector[[i]] + i * 0.25
}
```

But I'm sure there are better ways to do this in R.

With `sapply`?

```
sapply(seq_along(my.vector), function(i) my.vector[[i]] + i * 0.25)
```

OK, I get the same result, but it's less readable. Do you know of other cleaner ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of ways to approach this. One of the canonical methods uses `seq`:

```
myVectorSeq <- my.vector + seq(.25, 25, length.out=length(my.vector))
```

You can accomplish @lorenzo-rossi's method using `seq_len`:

```
myVectorSeq <- my.vector + (seq_len(length(my.vector)) * .25)
```

`seq_len`, which is faster than the more flexible `seq` function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new vector and then use a vectorized sum:

```
sums_vec = (1:length(my.vector)) * 0.25
my.vector + sums_vec
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `seq_along`

```
my.vector + seq_along(my.vector) *0.25
```